# Google Apps - Can no longer add an email alias

Tags: g-suite

I still have the legacy free Google apps.  I'm aware that I can't use a new domain as a secondary domain. But a domain alias to the existing main domain was always possible.

I have successfully added and verified a new domain alias to the existing primary domain.

> Domain alias for mydomain.com

However, from here everything seems to have changed. I can no longer add a new email alias to utilise this new domain.  How do I proceed, please?

I would like to receive and send emails via the new domain. (MX values are added and verified already)

Comment: To my knowledge, when you add a new domain alias it immediately becomes *an alias*, ie all the existing addresses work on this domain as well.  What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: So I'm trying to send an email to my new alias `support@mydomain.com`. I was expecting it to be redirected to my primary gmail domain.